# Given $h(x,y) = f(x^2y + y^3)$, and $f(t)$ is differentiable $\forall t$ and $f'(t) = \frac{1}{2}$, then

Tags: calculus

Given $h(x,y) = f(x^2y + y^3)$, and $f(t)$ is differentiable $\forall t$ and $f'(t) = \frac{1}{2}$, then compute $h'_x(1,1) + h'_y(1,1)$.

Well, I'm having difficulties using the chain rule to solve it. the answer has to be $3$.

Can you guys help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\displaystyle h_x'(1,1)=\left.\frac{\mathrm dh(x,1)}{\mathrm dx}\right|_{x\mathop=1}=\left.\frac{\mathrm df(x^2+1)}{\mathrm dx}\right|_{x\mathop=1}=f'\left((1)^2+1\right)\left.\frac{\mathrm d(x^2+1)}{\mathrm dx}\right|_{x\mathop=1}$

---

Alternatively: $f(t)=\dfrac12t+C$, so $h(x,y)=\dfrac12(x^2y+y^3)+C$.

Comment: Hey Kenny, I'm still having difficulties understanding what you've written. can you solve it without puting the values of $x,y$ in $f$'s brackets? When I did that and then used $x=y=1$ I didn't get to 3.

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake somewhere. Mind showing your steps?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question, but I will assume that $h: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, that $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and that $ h'_x =\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$.

If that is the case, we are only concerned with the chain rule for $f$. Let $t=x^2y+y^3$, then by the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{d f}{d t} \frac{d t}{d x} = f'(t) 2xy=xy
$$
since in this case the variable $y$ is held constant. Then
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{d f}{d t} \frac{d t}{d y} = f'(t) (x^2+3y^2)=(x^2+3y^2)/2
$$
since in this case $x$ is held constant and $f'(t)=1/2$. Hence we get:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(1,1)+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(1,1)= 1+ (1+3)/2=3
$$
Notice that there is an alternative method: since $f'(t)=1/2$, then we must have $f(t)=t/2+C$ where $C$ is some constant. Thus
$$
h(x,y)=f(x^2y+y^3)=(x^2y+y^3)/2+C
$$
Now you can compute the partials directly, and you'll get the same as above.